# toggle a specific div tag in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-api

I am building a simple ReactJS app to fetch GitHub user and display
 there repos. I am displaying the users in an array each have a details
 button, `onClick` only that specific users div tag must be displayed. I
 am able to pass username on click but `onClick` all users div tag are
 toggling. I want to display repos on clicking the details button.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import _ from 'lodash';

class SearchResults extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isOpen: false };
    this.toggleDetails = this.toggleDetails.bind(this);
  }

  toggleDetails(userName) {
    console.log(userName);

    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  }

  render() {
    const { userList, userCount } = this.props;
    const {isOpen} = this.state;
    console.log('in searchResult = ' + this.props.userCount)

    if (userList) {
      var list = _.map(userList, (row, key) => {
        return (
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center" key={row.id}
            style={{ border: '0px solid red' }}>
            <div className="card shadow-sm rounded" >
              <div className="card-body ">
                <div className="row ">
                  <div className="col-sm-2">
                    <img src={row.avatar_url} style={{ width: '80px', height: '80px' }}
                      className="rounded-circle" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-10" style={{ border: '0px solid black' }}>
                    <h5 className="card-title">  {row.login}</h5>
                    <p className="display-6 text-muted"> {row.html_url} </p>
                    <button className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm float-right"
                      onClick={() => this.toggleDetails(row.login)}  >
                      Details
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              {
                isOpen && 
                <table class="table table-striped" >
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Otto</td>
                      <td>@mdo</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Thornton</td>
                      <td>@fat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>the Bird</td>
                      <td>@twitter</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              }
            </div>
          </div>

        )
      })
    } else {
      var list = (
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center ">
          <div className="card shadow-sm rounded" >
            <div className="card-body ">
              <div className="row ">
                No results to show
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return (
      <div className="user-list">
        {userList ?
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div className="count">
              <h6 className="display-6">Total Results :  {userCount} </h6>
            </div>
          </div> :
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div className="count">
              <h6 className="display-6">Total Results :  {userCount} </h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        }
        {list}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isOpen` state is shared by all users. So you can try adding another state to keep the specific username which is open currently.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import _ from 'lodash';

class SearchResults extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isOpen: false, currentUser : '' };
    this.toggleDetails = this.toggleDetails.bind(this);
  }

  toggleDetails(userName) {
    console.log(userName);
    const currentUser = this.state.currentUser == userName ? '' : userName;
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen, currentUser:userName  });
  }

  render() {
    const { userList, userCount } = this.props;
    const {isOpen, currentUser} = this.state;
    console.log('in searchResult = ' + this.props.userCount)

    if (userList) {
      var list = _.map(userList, (row, key) => {
        return (
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center" key={row.id}
            style={{ border: '0px solid red' }}>
            <div className="card shadow-sm rounded" >
              <div className="card-body ">
                <div className="row ">
                  <div className="col-sm-2">
                    <img src={row.avatar_url} style={{ width: '80px', height: '80px' }}
                      className="rounded-circle" />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-10" style={{ border: '0px solid black' }}>
                    <h5 className="card-title">  {row.login}</h5>
                    <p className="display-6 text-muted"> {row.html_url} </p>
                    <button className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm float-right"
                      onClick={() => this.toggleDetails(row.login)}  >
                      Details
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              {
                isOpen && currentUser === row.login &&
                <table class="table table-striped" >
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Otto</td>
                      <td>@mdo</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Thornton</td>
                      <td>@fat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>the Bird</td>
                      <td>@twitter</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              }
            </div>
          </div>

        )
      })
    } else {
      var list = (
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center ">
          <div className="card shadow-sm rounded" >
            <div className="card-body ">
              <div className="row ">
                No results to show
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return (
      <div className="user-list">
        {userList ?
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div className="count">
              <h6 className="display-6">Total Results :  {userCount} </h6>
            </div>
          </div> :
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div className="count">
              <h6 className="display-6">Total Results :  {userCount} </h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        }
        {list}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

Comment: isOpen && currentUser === row.login &&
                <table class="table table-striped" >......